# How do I recursively create a Textures directory in every existing directory in Bash and then delete them?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, rm, mkdir

Lets say that I have the following structure:

```
./
├── Dir1
├── Dir2
│   ├── SubDir1
│   │   └── SubSubDir1
│   └── SubDir2
└── Dir3
    └── SubDir1
```

Use this to make the test structure:

```
mkdir -p Dir1 Dir2/SubDir1/SubSubDir1 Dir2/SubDir2 Dir3/SubDir1
```

I would like to create a `Texture` folder in every directory to include the current location so it would look like this (All new `Texture` directories are marked with `*`):

```
./
├── Dir1
│   └── Textures*
├── Dir2
│   ├── SubDir1
│   │   ├── SubSubDir1
│   │   │   └── Textures*
│   │   └── Textures*
│   ├── SubDir2
│   │   └── Textures*
│   └── Textures*
├── Dir3
│   ├── SubDir1
│   │   └── Textures*
│   └── Textures*
└── Textures*
```

Then I would also be able to delete these same folders after I work with them. You can assume that there are no other directories named `Textures` that need to be saved.

---

So I would like to create a `Textures` directory in the current directory and all of its subdirectories. And I would like to be able to delete every directory named `Textures` when I am done moving files around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a loop...

```
shopt -s globstar                   # turn on recursive globbing
for d in **/; do                    # for every directory
    echo mkdir -p "$d"Textures      # make a new directory inside named Textures
done
```

Remove `echo` after testing to actually create the directories.

You can turn off `globstar` with `shopt -u globstar`, but it is off by default, and will be off with you start a new shell.

Do your things...

Then to remove the directories, first `find` them

```
find -type d -name "Textures"
```

Then if the output looks OK, add `-delete`

```
find -type d -name "Textures" -delete
```

Comment: Just a minute faster than me... Good job ;-)

Comment: Could you shorten the loop to `mkdir -p **/Textures`? I would test it myself, but I'm not at home.

Comment: @wjandrea that just created a directory named "**" with a child directory of Textures.

Comment: @kingcobra1986 Ah, whoops. I forgot how globs work. :|

Comment: Thats alright I tried something earlier and it was trying to recursively create a Texture directories inside of themselves making it look like `./Textures/Textures/Textures/Textures/....` and it kept on going.